# ListView DataTemplate аномальная ширина

Tags: xaml, uwp, binding, stackpanel

Есть листвью , он должен быть горизонтальный , при объявлении dataTemplate появляется неизвестная ширина элемента , а нужно чтобы элементы располагались друг за другом.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding AccentColors}">
                        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <RadioButton GroupName="AccentColors" 
                                             HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                             Style="{StaticResource rbtnRectStyle}" 
                                             Background="{Binding}"
                                             BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="White"
                                                />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
```

Сейчас так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А нужно вот так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Причем ширина самого radioButton нормальная , такая как должна быть , а вот ширина DataTemplate намного больше чем нужно.